# How to set the local sql server database connection for authentication and authorization in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, security

When i configure user security by asp.net configuration tool.Here my defaults security tables are created in same application in App_Data under ASPNETDB database.so how can i maintain those tables in my dedicated sql server.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can check this asp forum [Link](http://forums.asp.net/t/1393794.aspx) it shows you how to embed the membership tables in a custom database instead of ASPNETDB.. also check this [Link](http://www.mattwrock.com/post/2009/10/14/Implementing-custom-Membership-Provider-and-Role-Provider-for-Authinticating-ASPNET-MVC-Applications.aspx) for an explanation about membership providers.